# React conditional styling

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to style a button based on the fact that it is disabled. i made a state and stored my styling there however it gives me this error,

`The`style `prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.`

i read couple inquiries like that but honestly i couldnt get it.
As long as it gets the job done. it doesnt have to be a state where to store the styling. so any other ideas are appreciated , thanks in advance

```
function Reserve() {
const [client,setClient] = useState(1)
const [notif,setNotif] = useState(false)
const [styling,setStyling] = useState({backgroundColor:''})

function addClient() {
    setClient(prevClient=>prevClient+1)
}

function reduceClient(event) {
    if (client > 1) {
    setClient(prevClient=>prevClient-1) 
    setNotif(false)}
    else {
    event.preventDefault()
    setStyling({backgroundColor:'Grey'})
    }

}
    return <main>
        Reservation table
        Number of people <span>{client}</span>
        <div>{notif}</div>
        <button className="adtbtn" onClick={addClient}>+</button>
        <button className="mnsbtn" onClick={reduceClient} disabled={notif} style={styling.backgroundColor}>-</button>
    </main>
}
```

I also tried disabling the button using a state instead of prevent.default() but that gave me bunch of bugs like pressing the deecrement button before the increement will make it faulty.

Comment: You should specify `style={styling}`, not `style={styling.backgroundColor}`. You want to supply the entire object, not just the `backgroundColor` value.

Comment: it worked out. thanks for that, but is there anyway to make toggle of the colors more dynamic. instead of having to press the buttons everytime ?

Comment: Specifying an inline `style` prop is generally considered a bit hacky – better to define the styling in a separate class (perhaps using the handy [`classnames` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)), or a styling framework such as [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) or [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction).